# in javascript, create Array from an iterator

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator, ecmascript-6

given an `iterator`, what's the best way to create an `Array`?

for example,

```
let map = new Map();
map.set( 'key1', 'data' );
map.set( 'key2', 'more data' );
...
// now, wish to have an array of keys
let arr = //??// map.keys()  //??//
```

I could do something lame like

```
function iter2array( iter ) {
  let arr = new Array();
  for( let e in iter ) arr.push(e);
  return arr;
}
```

but there has to be a better way.

Comment: Please remember an iterator can be infinite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Array.from(map.keys()) // ['key1', 'key2']
```

> The [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method creates a new Array instance from an
>   array-like or iterable object.

Comment: works great. firefox supports, but not yet in chrome or nodejs. any other ideas